# D3js: When to use .datum() and .data()?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I often see `.datum` when an area chart is used.  For example:

```
svg = d3.select("#viz").append("svg").datum(data)
```

Are there any rules of thumb for when `.datum` is needed?

```
var area = d3.svg.area()  
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })  
    .y0(height)  
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.y); });  

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")  
    .attr("width", width)  
    .attr("height", height);  

svg.append("path") 
    .datum(data)
    .attr("d", area);
```

Comment: Some useful insight around this topic can be found in this [other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41819109/1446845)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think the documentation gives a good answer to this question: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-datum.

Basically, the point is that in some cases you are not interested in the enter/exit sets when you do a selection. If this is the case, which often seems to be the case for the full chart, you use datum.

**Update:** It depends: when you expect no dynamic updates, which seems to be the case in your given example, datum is okay. Why? Because there is no path svg element yet, there is only one path element and once it is added it will not change.

If you where to have multiple path elements and dynamic changes (e.g. after each second the oldest data element gets removed and a new one gets added), than you *will* need data. This will give you three sets: the sets of graphic elements for which no data exists any longer, the set of elements for which the data is updated and the set of elements for which no data item existed before (respectively, the enter, update and exit sets). Once you need this I suggest you read up on the d3 documentation.

Obviously, calculating these three sets is not without a cost. In practice, this should only become a problem when you're working with "large" (I think d3 scales up to 10s of thousands of items) data sets.

Comment: Thanks, for answering. I added some more code for a basic area chart. I suppose I am unclear as to why in this instance I am using .datum instead of .data. I'm sure a better understanding of D3 is the answer! and that's what I'm after.

Comment: If you were to have only one path element and dynamic changes, should I use data or datum? For example, I have a line chart, but only one line in the chart, should I use data?

Comment: new link? https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/#selection_datum

Answer (score 11):

A very good tutorial with example is here.    http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/#data

Answer (score 7):

Others linked to the [tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/#data), but I think the [API reference on selection.datum](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#datum) gives the accepted answer:

> Gets or sets the bound data for each selected element. Unlike the
> `selection.data` method, this method **does not compute a join (and thus
> does not compute enter and exit selections).**

Since it does not compute a join, it does not need to know a key function. Therefore, notice the signature difference between the two, **only the `data` function accepts a key function**

- `selection.datum([value])`
- `selection.data([values[, key]])`

I think the tutorial for `data` gives another more basic difference which is analogous to the meaning of the words "data" and "datum". That is, **"data" is plural, the "datum" is singular**. Therefore, data can be joined in two ways:

> Joined to **groups** of elements via `selection.data`.
>
> Assigned to **individual** elements via `selection.datum`.

@Hugolpz' [gist](https://gist.github.com/hugolpz/824446bb2f9bc8cce607) gives nice examples of the significance of "groups" vs "individuals". Here, `json` represents an array of data. Notice how `datum` binds the entire array to one element. **If we want to achieve the same with `data` we must first put json inside another array.**

- `var chart = d3.select("body").append("svg").data([json])`
- `var chart = d3.select("body").append("svg").datum(json)`