# What is the difference D3 datum vs. data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Can someone please explain the difference between datum() and data() in D3.js? I see both being used and I am not sure why you should choose one over the other?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

I found the correct answer here from Mike himself:

[D3 - how to deal with JSON data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086167/d3-how-to-deal-with-json-data-structures)

If you want to bind your data to a single SVG element, use

```
(...).data([data])
```

or

```
(...).datum(data)
```

If you want to bind your data to multiple SVG elements

```
(...).data(data).enter().append("svg")
```

.....

Comment: Thank you for this!  the fact that you put data([data]) passing and array just helped me realize a bug I couldn't figure out for the past week!  Thank you so much... always such stupid things that are wrong.

Comment: data() performs a join, datum() does not.

Comment: Just keep in mind, in case if there are more data array elements than SVG elements when binding data with `enter()`, d3 will bind rest of array elements with newly created SVG elements.

Answer (score 69):

After having looked into this a bit, I've found that the answers here on SO are not complete as they only cover the case when you invoke `selection.data` and `selection.datum` with an input `data` parameter. Even in that scenario, the two behave differently if the selection is a single element versus when it contains multiple elements. Moreover, both of these methods can also be invoked without any input arguments in order to query the bound data/datum in the selection, in which case they once again behave differently and return different things.

Edit - I posted a slightly more detailed answer to this question [here](https://www.intothevoid.io/data-visualization/understanding-d3-data-vs-datum/), but the post below pretty much captures all the key points regarding the two methods and how they differ from each other.

**When supplying** `data` as **an input argument**

- `selection.data(data)` will attempt to perform a data-join between the elements of the `data` array with the selection resulting in the creation of `enter()`, `exit()` and `update()` selections that you can subsequently operate on. The end result of this is if you pass in an array `data = [1,2,3]`, an attempt is made to join each individual data element (i.e. datum) with the selection. Each element of the selection will only have a single datum element of `data` bound to it.
- `selection.datum(data)` bypasses the data-join process altogether. This simply assigns the entirety of `data` to all elements in the selection as a whole without splitting it up as in the case of data-joins. So if you want to bind an entire array `data = [1, 2, 3]` to every DOM element in your `selection`, then `selection.datum(data)` will achieve this.

> ***Warning:*** Many people believe that `selection.datum(data)` is equivalent to `selection.data([data])` but this is only true if
>   `selection` **contains a single element**. If `selection` contains
>   multiple DOM elements, then `selection.datum(data)` will bind the
>   entirety of `data` to every single element in the selection. In
>   contrast, `selection.data([data])` only binds the entirety of `data`
>   to the first element in `selection`. This is consistent with the
>   data-join behavior of `selection.data`.

**When supplying no `data` input argument**

- `selection.data()` will take the bound datum for each element in the selection and combine them into an array that is returned. So, if your `selection` includes 3 DOM elements with the data `"a"`, `"b"` and `"c"` bound to each respectively, `selection.data()` returns `["a", "b", "c"]`. It is important to note that if `selection` is a single element with (by way of example) the datum `"a"` bound to it, then `selection.data()` will return `["a"]` and not `"a"` as some may expect.
- `selection.datum()` only makes sense for a single selection as it is defined as returning the datum **bound to the first element** of the selection. So in the example above with the selection consisting of DOM elements with bound datum of `"a"`, `"b"` and `"c"`, `selection.datum()` would simply return `"a"`.

> Note that even if `selection` has a single element, `selection.datum()` and `selection.data()` return different values. The former returns the bound datum for the selection (`"a"` in the example above) whereas the latter returns the bound datum within an array (`["a"]` in the example above).

Hopefully this helps clarify how `selection.data` and `selection.datum()` differ from each other both when providing data as an input argument and when querying for the bound datum by not providing any input arguments.

PS - The best way to understand how this works is to start with a blank HTML document in Chrome and to open up the console and try adding a few elements to the document and then start binding data using `selection.data` and `selection.datum`. Sometimes, it's a lot easier to "grok" something by doing than by reading.

Comment: HamsterHuey has shown this already, but it might be a helpful reminder to recall that "datum" is singular and "data" is plural. Hence .datum applies to a single element's associated information.

Answer (score 42):

Here are some good links:

- Good discussion on D3 "data()":
  [Understanding how D3.js binds data to nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481497/understanding-how-d3-js-binds-data-to-nodes)
- [D3 for Mere Mortals](http://www.recursion.org/d3-for-mere-mortals/)
- [Mike Bostock's D3 Wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections)

Per the latter:

> `# selection.data([values[, key]])`
>
> Joins the specified array of data with the current selection. The
>   specified values is an array of data values, such as an array of
>   numbers or objects, or a function that returns an array of values.
>
> ...
>
> `# selection.datum([value])`
>
> Gets or sets the bound data for each selected element. Unlike the
>   selection.data method, this method does not compute a join (and thus
>   does not compute enter and exit selections).

Comment: given those definitions - i am still confused why you would ever need/want to use datum()

Comment: One more example that might help makes things clearer: http://ngokevin.com/blog/d3/.  NOTES: 1) Kevin's definition: "The datum is the data binded to the element." 2) Note how in Kevin's examples we "incorporate" the dataset with "data()" ... but we "use" a subset by referencing a "datum()".

Comment: @josephmisiti Just incase anyone else comes here 8 years later. The difference between data and datum becomes obvious when dealing with a lot of nodes. Try creating a line chart using every daily close price for Amazon. With data you will end up with A LOT of path nodes (and a huge svg). With datum you only have one path node. The difference is a factor of 1000.

Answer (score 7):

I think the explanation given by HamsterHuey is the best so far.
To expand on it and give a visual representation of the differences I created a sample document that illustrates at least part of the differences between `data` and `datum`.

The below answer is more of an opinion derived from using these methods, but I am happy to be corrected if I'm wrong.

This example can be run below or [in this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/e4m6j2d8/2/).

```
const data = [1,2,3,4,5];
const el = d3.select('#root');

 el
  .append('div')
  .classed('a', true)
  .datum(data)
  .text(d => `node => data: ${d}`);

const join= el
.selectAll('div.b')
.data(data);

join
.enter()
.append('div')
.classed('b', true)
.text((d, i) => `node-${i + 1} => data: ${d}`)
```

I think that `datum` is simpler to grasp since it doesn't do a join, but of course this also mean it has different use cases.

To me one big difference - although there are more - is the fact that `data` is just the natural way of doing (live) updates on a d3 chart, as the whole enter/update/exit pattern makes it simple, once you get it.

`datum` on the other hand seems to me to be more suited for static representations. In the example below for example I could achieve the same result my looping on the original array and accessing the data by index like so:

```
data.map((n, i) => {
 el
  .append('div')
  .classed('a', true)
  .datum(data)
  .text(d => `node-${n} => data: ${d[i]}`);
});
```

Try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/e4m6j2d8/6/

Again, I think this is way easier to grasp as you keep free from the mental burden coming from the enter/update/exit pattern, but as soon you need to update or change the selection you will surely be better off resorting to `.data()`.

```js
const data = [1,2,3,4,5];
const el = d3.select('#root');

 el
  .append('div')
  .classed('a', true)
  .datum(data)
  .text(d => `node => data: ${d}`);

const join= el
.selectAll('div.b')
.data(data);

join
.enter()
.append('div')
.classed('b', true)
.text((d, i) => `node-${i + 1} => data: ${d}`)
```

```css
/* Ignore all the css */
html {
  font-family: arial;
}

.l {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.l-a {
  background: #cf58e4;
}
.l-b {
  background:  #42e4e4;
}

.a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #cf58e4;
}

.b {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #42e4e4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.6.0/d3.min.js"></script>


<div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
  <span class="l l-a"></span> .datum() <br />
  <span class="l l-b"></span> .data()
</div>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the difference between data and datum is the number of elements bound. Data is for a list of elements while datum specifies only one element. For example, `d3.selectAll('div').data([1,2,3])` means to bind a list of elements (i.e., 1,2,3) to three different div. You might then chain the code with `.enter().append('div')` to create a new div for each new element. On the other side, `d3.select('div').datum(1)` means to bind element 1 to the div element.

You might note that we can also do something like `d3.select(div).datum([1,2,3])`. It is not the same as `d3.selectAll('div').data([1,2,3])`. `d3.select(div).datum([1,2,3])` treats `[1,2,3]` as only one element to bind to the div element, just like `div => [1,2,3]`. While `d3.selectAll('div').data([1,2,3])` treats `[1,2,3]` as a list of element such that it will bind each of the element inside the array to each div element, just like `div => 1; div => 2; div => 3`.