# Array within bound data (dynamically generating d3.svg.line with constancy) with d3.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to (dynamically) generate a set of `div`s, bound to some data, each div which contains some text and an SVG with a line.

If I want to make one at a time, this code works:

```
var ccg = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];

var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                      .x(function(d, i) { return width-(i*10); })
                      .y(function(d, i) { return height-d; })

var myContainer = d3.select("body").append("div")

var svgContainer = myContainer.append("svg")
                                 .attr("width", "10px")
                                 .attr("height", "10px");

var correlogram = svgContainer.append("path")
                         .attr("d", lineFunction(ccg))
```

So far so good. Now I want to update an array of data and have it dynamically have it update the DOM:

```
var width=100,
    height=100;

var clusters = [
{id: "1",
    ccg: [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10] },
{id: "2", 
    ccg: [41, 101, 11, 51, 21, 11] },
{id: "3", 
    ccg: [42, 130, 13, 53, 21, 101] },
]

var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                    .x(function(d, i) { return width-(i*10); })
                    .y(function(d, i) { return height-d; })
                    .interpolate("step-after");

var clusterView = d3.select("body").append("div")

var clusterDivs = clusterView.selectAll(".cluster")
                        .data(clusters, function(d) {return d.id});

var cluster = clusterDivs.enter()
                        .insert("div", ".cluster")

var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                     .x(function(d, i) { return width-(i*10); })
                     .y(function(d, i) { return height-d; })
                     .interpolate("step-after");

var svgContainer = cluster.append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height);


svgContainer.append("path")
.data(function (d) {return d.ccg;})
.enter()
.attr("d", function(d) {return lineFunction(d)})

cluster.append("div")
    .text(function(d) { return d.id; });
```

... I get an error. `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'ccg' of undefined"`.

I've tried all sorts of things: putting the function directly into the `.attr` seems to 'work' except it just doesn't return any output for that attribute.

Basically, given that input array `clusters`: how can I generate a different line from each sub-array `ccg`? I've read the tutorial on nested selections, but not sure it actually answers my question, since you can't bind each line vertex to a data point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/9my6Lznc/

Replace:

```
svgContainer.append("path")
  .data(function (d) {return d.ccg;})
  .enter()
  .attr("d", function(d) {return lineFunction(d)})
```

with:

```
svgContainer.append("path")
  .datum(function (d) {return d.ccg;})
  .attr("d", function(d) {return lineFunction(d)})
```

Switching `data` for `datum` and getting rid of `enter()`. For more discussion on the difference between `data` and `datum` see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13728584/3442309.

`data` joins an array, whereas you have objects (eg `{id: "2", ccg: Array[6]}`)