# D3 Line and Path - graph line doesn't show

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

...I'm porting a graph over from v3 to v4 and I've hit a wall with respect to *path* and *line*.

Here's what I believe to be the salient section:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
pdata = [
        {
            "date": "2018-01-01",
            "marketPrice": 3131
        },
        {
            "date": "2018-01-02",
            "marketPrice": 3151
        }
];  

// loop that transforms "date" to new Date(), marketPrice to numeric 
// *** added during edit ***

// format the data
pdata.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = new Date (d.date); // difference between this and Ref(3) is...
    // ref(3) calls a time parser rather than instantiate new Date()
  d.marketPrice = +d.marketPrice;
  //console.log("parsing date into: -- Date: " + d.date + " -- Market Price: " + d.marketPrice);
});

// linear scaling functions - xscale() and yscale()
// *** added during edit ***

// Create scales (added in edit)
var xscale = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([
        d3.min(pdata, function (d){return d.date}), 
        d3.max(pdata, function (d){return d.date})
      ])
      .range([GRAPHLEFT, GRAPHRIGHT]);

var yscale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([
        d3.min(pdata, function (d){return d.marketPrice}), 
        d3.max(pdata, function (d){return d.marketPrice})
      ])
      .range([GRAPHBOTTOM,GRAPHTOP]);

// axis functions omitted ...these work predictably

svg.append("path")
    .data([pdata])
    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 3)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("d", lineFunc);

var lineFunc = d3.line()
  .x(function (d) {
    console.log("Graphing x as: " + xscale(d.date)); // updated during edit
    return (xscale(d.date)); // updated during edit ... reveals as NaN
  })
  .y(function (d) {
    console.log("Graphing y as: " + yscale(d.marketPrice)); // updated during edit ... reveals as NaN
    return (yscale(d.marketPrice));
  });
```

I can't confirm that the callbacks from `lineFunc()` are actually getting called. (*Now resolved in accord with answer below*)

In my page, the axes appear, but no plot line appears.

I'm working from these references and models:

(1) - https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#line

(2) - https://bl.ocks.org/pstuffa/26363646c478b2028d36e7274cedefa6

(3) - https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/402dd382a51a4f6eea487f9a35566de0

Comment: First of all and not related with the console.log issue, you're missing the scales in the line generator. For instance, you cannot have a string like `"2018-01-02"` for the x position! Also, use `datum(pdata)` instead of `data([pdata])`.

Comment: The scaling appears offstage in this case. There's a forEach loop (implied in the comments) that transforms the date string by subjecting each date element to a "new Date()" replacement. (I've added it as an edit to the OP) -- I could not find doc on the distinction between `datum([pdata])` and `data(pdata)` - I'm looking the wrong place in the API doc, and the examples seem a little contradictory.

Comment: ...also, I have an offstage function xscale() -- Is it your assertion that in `lineFunc()` my code should `.x(d => {return xscale(d.date)})` instead of `.x(d => {return d.date})` -- cuz I've also tried that.

Comment: I did find a lucid consideration of the difference between datum(pdata) and data(pdata) ... a [stackoverflow node here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728402/what-is-the-difference-d3-datum-vs-data), and [article here](https://www.intothevoid.io/data-visualization/understanding-d3-data-vs-datum/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...dunno why it took me so long to find the answer, but along the way I had the opportunity to scrub over the D3 API doc and examples with a fine toothed comb.

The final answer is actually supplied above in comments.

I was using `data([pdata])` instead of `datum(pdata)` and when I corrected the code fully, the issue was solved. (For a while, I had `datum([pdata])` and that didn't work out for reasons explained in [this fine article](https://www.intothevoid.io/data-visualization/understanding-d3-data-vs-datum/).

*Thanks Gerardo Fudado - and yes, I bought the silly t-shirt.*

Answer (score 2):

Despite `d3.line()` being a method (i.e., a function), `var lineFunc = d3.line().etc...` is a **function expression**, and, unlike function statement, it's not hoisted:

> Function expressions in JavaScript are not hoisted, unlike function declarations. You can't use function expressions before you define them. ([MDN source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function))

Therefore, move `var lineFunc = d3.line().etc...`  to the top, before the `.attr("d", lineFunc)` for the path:

```
var lineFunc = d3.line()
    .x(function (d) {
    //etc... 

svg.append("path")
    .data([pdata])
    //etc..
    .attr("d", lineFunc);
```

PS: You still need a scale in the line generator. Your path will be appended in the SVG, but the x values will be timestamps and the y values the actual `marketPrice` values.

Comment: Moving the declaration made a difference. Thanks. That is actually a fundamental principle I should have picked up somewhere. As you can see, I'm coming at this language sideways.  Meanwhile, I'm cross-eyed from staring at my scaling function and cross checking against the model in Ref (3) above.  I'm going to add my scaling functions as an edit to the OP - maybe there's something that will stand out that I can't see.

Comment: Added the scaling function to OP. (meta: would it have been more effective to add it as a psuedo answer to make it stand out more in the conversation and retain the integrity of the node? I considered simply posting that business as a fresh question, but it seems more wholesome to resolve it completely here.)

Comment: Okay, an attempt to add answer suggests that correct approach is to edit the OP. (meta: personally, I find that more confusing when I come to a node, reading to find answer to my own issue. It means that when I read OP, the comments and answers don't reflect the original question. But okay...)