# d3.js adding legend to multiline series chart

Tags: javascript, dataset, d3.js, visualization

How would one add a legend to the multiline series chart? I tried but am not getting any legend to display.

The block here:

http://bl.ocks.org/3884955

has a flaw when the various series converge to the same point, like zero. All the labels will be overlayed on each other. Instead of going for these labels, a traditional legend would be useful.

I tried adding this

```
var legend = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "legend")
.attr("height", 100)
.attr("width", 100)
.attr('transform', 'translate(-20,50)');    

legend.selectAll('rect')
  .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", width)
  .attr("y", function(d, i){ return i *  20;})
  .attr("width", 10)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .style("fill", function(d) { 
    return color.domain(d3.keys(d[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "day"; }));
  });

legend.selectAll('text')
  .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", width)
  .attr("y", function(d, i){ return i *  20 + 9;})
  .text(function(d) {
  return d.name;
  });
```

to the end of the code, the key names (d.name) match how my data is formatted, but it does not display. At one point it showed all black boxes to the right of the graph so that means I am close but I am missing something important

any insight appreciated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Here](http://bl.ocks.org/4745936) is a fixed & refactored version of your code.

```
    var legend = svg.selectAll('g')
        .data(cities)
        .enter()
      .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'legend');

    legend.append('rect')
        .attr('x', width - 20)
        .attr('y', function(d, i){ return i *  20;})
        .attr('width', 10)
        .attr('height', 10)
        .style('fill', function(d) { 
          return color(d.name);
        });

    legend.append('text')
        .attr('x', width - 8)
        .attr('y', function(d, i){ return (i *  20) + 9;})
        .text(function(d){ return d.name; });
```

You need to use `enter()`, but `enter()` and `exit()` methods **cannot** be used with `datum()`. Quoting from the [d3 wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-datum)

> ## selection.datum([value])
>
> Gets or sets the bound data for each selected element. Unlike the selection.data method, this method does not compute a join (and thus does not compute enter and exit selections).

Comment: I addded a dot and your code worked for me. var legend = svg.selectAll('.g')

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the .enter() after .datum() function call.

```
legend.selectAll('rect')

  .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })

  .enter() // <======

  .append("rect")

  .attr("x", width)

  .attr("y", function(d, i){ return i *  20;})

  .attr("width", 10)

  .attr("height", 10)

  .style("fill", function(d) { 

    return color.domain(d3.keys(d[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "day"; }));
```

Before appending the "rect" you must use the enter() function see link for exact explanation [Click Here](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449339739/_data.html)

Comment: hm, I find some discrepancies with that logic, in the example graph `city` variable in some places start off with `.append("text")` then `.datum(...)` with no `enter()` after that, but just attribute modifying. Also, when I did add `enter()` my console said object has no `enter()` and gave an error

Comment: I could be wrong but i think the confusion comes from the fact (if i am reading this correctly) .datum() adds/changes the value to an existing element in your selection. In your code where you state "legend.selectAll('rect')" none exist and to create the initial join you would need to use ".data(data).enter()" to create new "rect" elements.

Comment: here's a good answer to the question about .data and .datum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181194/when-do-i-need-to-use-or-not-use-datum-when-appending-an-svg-element