# How do I create a D3 graph with multiple time series already in variables (i.e. not using d3.tsv())?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, time-series

I'm looking at the following [D3 time series graph example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955) ([original source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775962/d3-js-adding-legend-to-multiline-series-chart)), which uses `d3.tsv()` to add the different series to the graph.

Assume my data is in the following format:

```
var data1 = [{"date": "2011-07-16", "data1": 413.0}, {"date": "2011-07-17", "data1": 412.0}, ...]
var data2 = [{"date": "2011-07-16", "data2": 200.0}, {"date": "2011-07-17", "data2": 201.0}, ...]
var data3 = [{"date": "2011-07-16", "data3": 199.0}, {"date": "2011-07-17", "data3": 195.0}, ...]
```

How can this example be modified to work with my data?

Comment: It's all in the function that creates `cities`. In there, add the different bits of data from the different arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is to merge your three data arrays into a single array that is in the same format as the Object returned by d3.tsv. For example, instead of calling d3.tsv(...) in the example, first merge your three data arrays, e.g.

```
// Create a merged list of data points
var data = [];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < data1.length; i++){
  data.push({date: data1[i].date, data1: data1[i].data1,
             data2: data2[i].data2, data3:    data3[i].data3, });
}
```

Then you can use `data` in the exact same manner in the rest of the script. Note that I am assuming that your data points are already sorted by date (as in your example), and that every date has three data points.